# locking a database in mongodb for writing using python(no threads)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

to perform some write operations on mongodb I have to lock the database i.e no other process should neither read or write.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how to apply lock to database for writing

Comment: Would the answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626838/mongodb-4-0-transactions-acid-read-write help you ?